# swiper not working on latest version of chrome (70)

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am trying to get swiper to work. I have tried it on edge and firefox and it seems to work. However it doesnt work on chrome.

To reproduce, visit http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/ using chrome and select the first demo, try swiping, it doesnt swipe. There is nothing n the console to suggest  any scripting errors. This did used to work in chrome, so my guess is that an update in chrome has caused it to fail.

Does anyone have a fix or a workaround?

It seems to be fine in Edge and firefox....

Comment: Works fine here on desktop and mobile

Comment: I should add - the problem occurs on the latest version of chrome desktop -  what version of chrome desktop are you using/testing against?

Comment: 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: hmm - me too! You using touch movements and not the keyboard though right...?

Answer (score 0):

Same here !
Chrome 70 supresses touch events on desktops :
"ontouch* members on window, document, and element are disabled by default on desktop devices"

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4764225348042752

Any workarounds ?
btw , "slick" swiper (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) seems to be working well with touch